# Matlab: How can i read the value (string or number) of a variable?

Tags: matlab

Maybe the question is strange but anyway....
How can i read the value (string or number) of the variable **number_of_plots** or **color**? (i want to use the variable/array diagram options to solve this problem)

My Code:

```
diagramoptions = []; 
wholecontent = fileread('aaa.txt') 
sections = regexp(wholecontent, '\*+([^*]+)\*+([^*]+)', 'tokens') 
for section = sections 
   switch(strtrim(section{1}{1})) 
         case 'Diagram Options' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file 
            keyvalues = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return 
            diagramoptions = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'}) 
        otherwise 
            warning('Unknown section: %s', section{1}{1}) 
     end 
  end 
openvar diagramoptions
```

My Input "aaa.txt":

```
******************* Diagram Options****************
number_of_plots=4
header=Number of cycles
color=red
xlabel= RPM
ylabel= degree
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive way of doing it... It doesn't scale well and it does unnecessary work.. But it's something for you to build upon.

```
fileId = fopen('test.txt');
c = textscan(fileId, '%s', 'Delimiter', '=');
fclose(fileId);

for i = 1: length(c{1,1})
    if (strcmp(c{1,1}{i,1}, 'number_of_plots'))
        number_of_plots = c{1,1}{i+1,1};
    elseif strcmp(c{1,1}{i,1}, 'color')
        color = c{1,1}{i+1,1};
    end
end
```

So, read in the file and delimit at `=` makes you know that any match on e.g. `number_of_plots` is in the next row. So just loop through and pick it out.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It works. But in my opinion a little bit complicated.... There must be an easy way... if you open "openvar diagramoptions" you see the first column has the name Key and the second column has the name Value. So i think you have to ask "which value has the key "number_of_plots". But i dont know how to do it ....

Comment: Your question was to solve it.. And I don't see why it's complicated? Its basically 2 if statements that read clearly what happens.. But it's surely more lines of code than I would write in my own app (I haven't used Matlab in ages).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `eval` in order to run a .txt file as it was a .m file:

```
fid = fopen('aaa.txt') %open the file

tline = fgetl(fid); %read the first line
while ischar(tline)
if ~isempty(strfind('tline','number_of_plots')) | ~isempty(strfind('tline','color='))
        try  %if it's possible matlab execute this line
        eval(tline)
        end
end
    tline = fgetl(fid); %read the next line
end

fclose(fid)
```

But in this case you need to add some quotation marks to your aaa.txt so that matlab can create the variables:

```
******************* Diagram Options****************
number_of_plots=4
header='Number of cycles'
color='red'
xlabel='RPM'
ylabel='degree'
```

Comment: hello, i need the information from diagramoptions.... i know the result is the same if i evaluate the .txt File - but the structure of my .txt File is changing...